# Page is numbered on ToC but not on the page itself

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

You guys, I am working on my thesis and facing an annoying issue: I have to number the pre-Chapter1 pages with roman numbers and, after that, with Arabian numbers. I've already tried several solutions and I don't know what else to do.

My header is:

```
\documentclass[ruledheader]{abnt}
\usepackage[portuguese,ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx}
\usepackage{abnt-alf}
\usepackage[alf]{abntcite}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.pdf,.mps,.png}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}

\include{capa}
\include{folharosto}
```

These 'includes' on the last two lines are the page 1 and 2. I am also using the abnt document class, since it is the class that defines the Brazilian thesis rules.

So, I've tried the default configuration:

```
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{roman}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofalgorithms

\begin{resumo}
...
\end{resumo}

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{Introdução}
...
```

However, the toc is showing roman and Arabic mixed together, before the Chapter 1. Also, I didn't get the numbers on the lof and lot pages. Only the loa, resumo and abstract pages have numbers, but Arabian ones:

[image]

The only way I get a correct toc is this one:

```
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{roman}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofalgorithms
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{5}

\begin{resumo}
...
\end{resumo}

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{Introdução}
...
```

And I get this:

[image]

The ToC is correct, but even this way, the LoF and LoT don't have roman numbers on their pages. Actually these two never get page numbers, even if they are correct on ToC. The \loa, resumo and abstract pages have its roman page numbers showing correctly on its pages. What should I do in order to get the roman numbers on LoF and LoT showing on its pages?

Ps: there is no `\pagestyle{empty}` in my text.

Comment: If you are using `abnt` class it should take care of page numbering. It is better to not use any personal command to change it. Are you using the last version of `abntex2`?

Comment: See here http://www.ctan.org/pkg/abntex2 how to use ABsurdas Normas de TeX.

Comment: @Sigur, I am using `abntx`, not abntex2. Since my text is already too big, I am afraid that if I change it to abntex2 class (that I've never used before), several issues my occur.

Comment: Besides, I've seen the abntex2 documentation and the \lof use is pretty much the same. So, I think that this issue is a particular problem that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The commands order did the trick. So, if anyone else eventually face this kind of situation, just change the commands order. In my case, this order solved the issue:

```
...
\tableofcontents    
\listofalgorithms
\pagenumbering{roman}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
 ...
```